# Showing that the composite function of f and g (fg) is continuous at 0.

Tags: analysis

I need to show that the composite function $fg: R\to R$ is continuous at 0 when we already know that $f:R^2\to R$ and $g:R\to R^2$ are already continuous at 0, as well as the fact that g(0) = 0.

I have used the definition provided:

Let $A ⊂ R^n.$ A function $f : A → Rm$ is continuous at x ∈ A, if for all
$\epsilon > 0,$ there exists δ > 0 such that for any y ∈ A with |y − x| ≤ δ we have $|f(y) − f(x)| < \epsilon$. If f is continuous at every point of A, then f is said to be continuous.

Narrowing down that A will be $R^2$ for f and R for g, giving |y| ≤ δ implies $||f(y) - f(0)| < \epsilon$ as well as implying $||g(y)|| < \epsilon$

I am struggling to go from here and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with an $\epsilon > 0$, and prove the existence of a $\delta > 0$, which satisfies all the conditions.

You want to show that $fg$ is continuous at zero. So for this, choose $\epsilon > 0$. Note that for this $\epsilon$, there is some $\delta_1 > 0$ such that if $|x_1 - 0| < \delta_1$ then $|f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon$. This is by continuity of $f$.

Similarly, by continuity of $g$, there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $|g(x) - g(0)| < \delta_1$ whenever $||x - 0|| < \delta_2$.

Finally, note that if $|x| < \delta_2$, then $|g(x)| < \delta_1$ by the above statement, and therefore $|fg(x) - fg(0)| < \epsilon$ since $|g(x)| < \delta_1$. Hence, if we take $\delta = \delta_2$, then $|x| < \delta \implies |fg(x) - fg(0)| < \epsilon$. Therefore, since this happens for every $\epsilon$, we are done i.e. $fg$ is continuous at zero.